# MS teams notifications for Confluence

Tags: confluence

Asking if anyone has played around with and got working MS Teams notifications with Confluence Date Center or On-Premise? I am looking at potentially sending approval notifications for document/page changes to MS Teams Chat. Hoping someone may have dabbled or offer some insight into this...

Not tried anything yet, i am looking into if this is possible and easily achieved task. I don't want to waste too much time on it if its too much work.

I am aware the cloud version can do it but sadly we are not using that for this task.

Thanks